Sealing bottom of the shed
I assembled a shed on a plywood platform and it's leaking from the bottom sides.
I'm thinking to apply sealant under metal plates but wondering if there is a better way to seal it.
Any ideas?



Assuming that metal bracket basically runs the whole perimeter, if you can loosen it from the plywood and slip a rubber gasket underneath (the refasten), that might do the trick.

Good idea, thanks!

use some clear flexseal from the inside.
